# Changing The Site URL doesn't work Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have a problem with Changing The Site URL in Wordpress. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.
I copy my website from **fryzjer.make4u.pl**. 
I created subdomen **demo1.make4u.pl** and took out my files from **fryzjer.make4u.pl**. 
When I enter to **demo1.make4u.pl** redirection me to **fryzjer.make4u.pl**.
I change code in file wp-config.php

```
<?php
/**
 * The base configuration for WordPress
 *
 * The wp-config.php creation script uses this file during the
 * installation. You don't have to use the web site, you can
 * copy this file to "wp-config.php" and fill in the values.
 *
 * This file contains the following configurations:
 *
 * * MySQL settings
 * * Secret keys
 * * Database table prefix
 * * ABSPATH
 *
 * @link https://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */
// ** MySQL settings - You can get this info from your web host ** //
define('WP_HOME','http://demo1.make4u.pl');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://demo1.make4u.pl');


/** The name of the database for WordPress */
define('DB_NAME', 'pawwlak_demo1');

/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', 'pawwlak_demo1');

/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', '*******');

/** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

/** Database Charset to use in creating database tables. */
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8mb4');

/** The Database Collate type. Don't change this if in doubt. */
define('DB_COLLATE', '');


/**#@+
 * Authentication Unique Keys and Salts.
 *
 * Change these to different unique phrases!
 * You can generate these using the {@link https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/ WordPress.org secret-key service}
 * You can change these at any point in time to invalidate all existing cookies. This will force all users to have to log in again.
 *
 * @since 2.6.0
 */
define('AUTH_KEY',         '2zYYuJ)vQk.)[u9YZN|?nH$%,upKR.|M9LU~Ia?U<xR%_Nkjm-Y(0qCc2+>s[4~f');
define('SECURE_AUTH_KEY',  '*m0QP$nkR1p(DKM?mQvl5h`yI%8TcdNCE,S!Kdu9I6a~:&Wu/nXV?9pKW1n!&2xw');
define('LOGGED_IN_KEY',    'ekZe)AMW@r[rux$OB2WH<`B_l*+$[v8:^bNGqjps+kEF!|ENpm5gN<]8)p7cg7QE');
define('NONCE_KEY',        'dC1<i[BWhz*T#L(`8P`gz}J2/YA67?~Ps<0g G)@a1N_`Mx+nN^%MW4q)NU;.5/%');
define('AUTH_SALT',        'x.zML}$pIbtCGp-/A44kFZB[uLY~;0R9#I0]W~lc9DyLlKU`]HeUSk)$6/(75T}v');
define('SECURE_AUTH_SALT', 'dT`KJVh6|xjevK/3:#t3C?IcE0>q%} tFWkT-}I*H60wA|lf);Z1m9bV]G;*qwc/');
define('LOGGED_IN_SALT',   'GeDCcC$uR^6e(4(TjF94N$Yh<QIpt_?^q.Ixy{LBW=eez&Ql_7/CqS1r+R;uP+31');
define('NONCE_SALT',       'DO.kU/6]s<k<+kfbE`EWf$:f>5G%Q9WPGjE?^0AS3,&OcLfGnY6pgd.orwdq`~C(');

/**#@-*/

/**
 * WordPress Database Table prefix.
 *
 * You can have multiple installations in one database if you give each
 * a unique prefix. Only numbers, letters, and underscores please!
 */
$table_prefix  = 'wp_';

/**
 * For developers: WordPress debugging mode.
 *
 * Change this to true to enable the display of notices during development.
 * It is strongly recommended that plugin and theme developers use WP_DEBUG
 * in their development environments.
 *
 * For information on other constants that can be used for debugging,
 * visit the Codex.
 *
 * @link https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress
 */
define('WP_DEBUG', false);

/* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */

/** Absolute path to the WordPress directory. */
if ( !defined('ABSPATH') )
    define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');

/** Sets up WordPress vars and included files. */
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');
```

Do you know why it dosen't work?

Comment: You need to replace old the domaine by the new in all tables.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. Can you explain clearly?

Answer (score 1):

You defined the wrong constants. The top of your `wp-config.php` file should be:

```
define('HOME','http://demo1.make4u.pl');
define('SITEURL','http://demo1.make4u.pl');
```

*Note that `WP_HOME` became `HOME` and `WP_SITEURL` became `SITEURL`*.

Alternatively, if this does not work for you, try connecting to the database, navigate to the `wp_options` table, and adjust the entries for `home` and `siteurl` to your new URL's.

If you are confident in using SQL queries on your database, you can make use if [yuyokk's code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29697282/6049581) as a SQL Query which will do a comprehensive find/replace in your database:

**REMEMBER:** *Backup your database before attempting any SQL Queries!*

```
UPDATE wp_options
SET option_value = 'http://demo1.make4u.pl'
WHERE option_name = 'home';

UPDATE wp_options
SET option_value = 'http://demo1.make4u.pl'
WHERE option_name = 'siteurl';

UPDATE wp_posts
SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content,'http://fryzjer.make4u.pl','http://demo1.make4u.pl');

UPDATE wp_posts
SET guid = REPLACE(guid,'http://fryzjer.make4u.pl','http://demo1.make4u.pl');
```

Comment: I make as you wrote and it doesn't work. Do you know what can  I do?

Comment: Double check that you are pointing to the correct database in your `wp-config.php` - have you switched over to your new database? Did you run all 4 of the SQL Queries? What does your database show under wp_options->home?

Comment: Also, `demo1.make4u.pl` doesn't resolve to an IP address - has the server been setup yet?

Comment: I don't know. How can I check it?

Comment: You will have to check with your provider - ask your host (_make4u.pl?_)? Either way, none of these fixes will work until it's actually employed on a working webserver.