# Wordpress changing domain

Tags: wordpress

I'm back on some Wordpress projets, and I finished a test site using a local ".test" url.
So I decided to make it online on : http://example.com

I changed my wp-config.php with OVH data, the database connection is OK.
I also changed in phpMyAdmin the old url to the new url.

But Css files trying to load with the following url :

http://example.com/:/example.com/wp-includes/js/wp-emoji-release.min.js?ver=5.4.2

I can't make it work properly, do I have to do something else ? I think I followed every steps.
I juste bough OVH domain this morning, maybe I have to wait more ?

My .htaccess :

```
# BEGIN WordPress
# Les directives (lignes) entre 'BEGIN WordPress' et 'END WordPress' sont
# généré dynamiquement, et ne doivent uniquement être modifiées via les filtres WordPress.
# Toute modification des directives entre ces marqueurs sera outrepassée.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Thanks !

Comment: You need to change the url in the db [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29697144/change-site-url-and-wordpress-url-in-localhost)

Comment: I already did it ...

Answer (score 3):

1. Via your database backend, Click on your wp_options table, Locate the 'siteurl' and 'home' rows, Alter the URL by typing in a new one.
2. Log into your site using FTP or SSH and in your WordPress directory, edit the file titled 'wp-config.php'.

```
define('WP_HOME','http://ba-construction.fr');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://ba-construction.fr');
```

3. Login to your website via `wp-admin.php` and navigate to Settings -> General, here you'll see the HOME and SITE URL your WordPress site is configured to use.
4. You can even rename your `.htaccess` to `.htaccess.bak` or similar and let wordpress generate a new one - then any changes you've manually done to .htaccess you can update when you get back in.

If you gain access to your admin area, there are a number of plugins available to update all your files/links to the new domain url - then everything should be good to go! Just make sure you backup first. Eg: https://wordpress.org/plugins/velvet-blues-update-urls/

All of your links in your source are showing `://address....` or `ba-construction.test`. Double check your database entries and wp-config.php that you've changed, disable all of your plugins (yoast is still loading old data), check out those link refresh plugins, reactivate plugins and you should be good to go.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll try when I come back home.
I replaced every urls in the database for the new one, same in wp-config.php
So I thought it was all good ...